# Confused about a convention in pseudocode from Introduction to Algorithms

Tags: pseudocode, clrs

I have the follwoing convention in pseudocode, from the Introduction to Algorithims textbook:

> 8. Parameters are passed to a procedure by value: the called procedure receives
>      its own copy of the parameters, and if it assigns a value to a parameter, the
>      change is not seen by the calling procedure. When objects are passed, the
>      pointer to the data representing the object is copied, but the object’s fields are not. For example, if x is a parameter of a called procedure, the assignment
>      x ← y within the called procedure is not visible to the calling procedure. The
>      assignment f [x] ← 3, however, is visible.

What is a calling procedure and what does it mean to be visible or not to it?

Could someone explain to me what the quote wants to say?

Comment: Basically that primitives are passed by value and objects are passed by reference. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: See [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) wikipage

Answer (score 0):

Let fn1 be the parent scope of fn2, i.e fn2 is called inside fn1.
To answer your first question:
What is calling procedure?
fn1 = calling procedure
To answer the second question:
what does it mean to be visible or not to it?
Variables in fn1 are not visible to variables in side fn2
fn2 receives its copy of the variables through the parameters passed into fn2